# Difference between using oauth access token and login/apikey in bit.ly API

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, bit.ly

I have to convert long urls to short urls on server side using bit.ly APIs. I was thinking of using some existing PHP libraries to do so like : https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/Bitly/blob/master/bitly.php

This API requires login and api key to shorten urls. But after reading the bit.ly API docs, they suggest to use oauth access token to make calls instead of API key/login. Whats the right way to do this?

Comment: Hi coder, why don't you use google url shortner who has more request per day and with small piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using OAuth and an access token is the right way, given the choice. There are at least two other Bitly PHP clients that support OAuth:

- https://github.com/Falicon/BitlyPHP
- https://github.com/jsocol/bitly-api-php

(The latter is mine, and only support OAuth.)